# InfoPath - Copy values from Secondary Database Connection into Main Database connection

Tags: infopath, visual-studio, forms-services, infopath-rules, vba

I was Hoping that someone could help me with the problem that I have been having, I am trying to copy one repeating field from my Secondary Database Connection into my Main Database Connection. The Field in the Secondary Database connection has multiple records and I would like to copy all of them into my Main Database Connection Table.

I hope that makes sense.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? As I have tried a number of ways but no luck

Thank you for you're time :)

Answer (score 1):

The only approach I would see feasible is to use InfoPath with Code and attempt submission. For this, your primary connection must also support "Receive" data.

Alternative is also (i would recommend better) to consider using 2 external Lists as Data sources in SharePoint and rely on those - example here http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/289541/Creating-InfoPath-Forms-that-Save-to-SQL-Server-Database

Advantages are many, particularly the ease of InfoPath form creation, security, etc. however Repeatable Sections can only work if instead of using "Edit form with Infopath" in the ribbon, you go for Forms Library with a Form using these 2 data sources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marius, I'm afraid the only option that is feasible for me is to, use InfoPath with Code and attempt submission.

I would be grateful if you could advise me on how to start the VB code?

Comment: Be aware that adding code to the form, changes it to Administrator-published InfoPath form, requiring the solution deployment in SP-CA. A good series i found http://johanolivier.blogspot.ch/2010/08/infopath-2010-development-part-1-add.html